# Comparison for capital string and lowercase string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('G' < 'g')
```

The output is `True`, I don't understand.
Please help me to figure out, thanks.

Comment: What would you have expected?

Comment: In ascii,`G`==71,'`g`==103.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thank you so much, I understood